# lista indexada con ciclo for

Tags: python

Tengo que obtener un código CRC a partir de una lista dada
donde se hace operaciones lógicas con cada uno de los elementos de una lista 
así:

```
comand_buffer=[0x004c,0x004f,0x004f,0x0050,0x00ff,0x00ff,0x000d]
tam_cad=len(comand_buffer)
crc=0
#for i, value in enumerate(comand_buffer):
for i in range(0, 7): 
 data=comand_buffer[0]
 pos=(crc<<8) ^ data
 crc=crc_table[pos]^(crc << 8)



print "checksum: " + repr(crc)
```

Se manera manual, es decir incrementando `i` cada vez que ejecuto el programa funciona pero al hacer con el ciclo `for` sale el siguiente error

> crc=crc_table[pos]^(crc << 8)
>
> ```
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

La lista tiene 256 elementos, y la variable `pos` no supera el valor de 255

Comment: Revisaste los valores de data ? al menos a mi me dan un valor de 76, por eso pienso que puede darte el "list index out of range"

Comment: si, el código  funciona en C, al final decidí utilizar Cython e importar los valores desde C